# Member "name" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct xxx storage ref[] storage ref

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

Solifity 0.8.0

with struct

> struct Placeholder{ string a; uint256 b; }

> mapping(uint256 => Placeholder[]) public placeholder;

why this error

> Member "b" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct TestSM.Placeholderstorage ref[] storage ref.

is thrown when I try to get values?

> placeholder[token_id].b

Any help is more than appreciated. I'm blocked :/

Answer (score 0):

I solved with:

```
mapping(uint256 => Placeholder) public placeholder;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove [] - It's array of Placeholders:

```
mapping(uint256 => Placeholder) public placeholder;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).